# Please a suggest a more efficient way to perform the below regex ,it works on fine on small data but for large datasets it not working

Tags: regex, python-3.x, utf-8

I am reading a txt file, the file is utf-8 encoded.I have used regular expression to remove punctuation and non-ascii char ,after that i have to append <> in each word,when I am reading 5 records it works fine, but when I try to read the whole file it never finishes executing,

I am reading the file in the following way,after that

```
"""
encoding = 'utf8-*-'
    with io.open(testfile, 'r', encoding=encoding, newline='\n') as fin:
        text1=fin.read()

"""
```

I am using the following way to append <>

```
"""
line2= re.sub(r"(\w+)", r"<\1>", updated)
"""
```

I cannot attach sample or else I would have attached.
Here is the time take to execute for sample record which is of 9248 len
[image: Execution Time]

Comment: Can you write what is it your are asking? "I am reading a txt file..." is not a question. Please rewrite the title with your question.

Comment: Without knowing much more, I'm guessing you would benefit from chunking the reading of the file. Feel free to google it.

Comment: Thanks for the help,I will read about chunking